# John The Ripper, Invalid UTF-8

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I am cracking a very basic hash, which should result to hello after being cracked. But it does not..
Here's the error.

`root@kali:~/Desktop# john crack.txt --format=Raw-MD5 --wordlist: /usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt 
Warning: invalid UTF-8 seen reading /usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt
Using default input encoding: UTF-8
Loaded 52 password hashes with no different salts (Raw-MD5 [MD5 256/256 AVX2 8x3])
Remaining 50 password hashes with no different salts
Warning: no OpenMP support for this hash type, consider --fork=4
Press 'q' or Ctrl-C to abort, almost any other key for status
0g 0:00:00:00 DONE (2020-05-07 14:50) 0g/s 354600p/s 354600c/s 17730KC/s !@#$%..sss
Session completed`

Please tell what could be the solution.

Comment: Looks like the encoding on `rockyou.txt` is not UTF-8. Open it with a text editor that allows you to change the encoding back to UTF-8, and save the file.

Comment: I have done this already. But no help. It is UTF-8

Comment: In mostly every file it says the same.

Comment: make sure you remove the space before /usr........    it should be directly after the =   so you should have --wordlist=/usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, you have wrong syntax. It should be `--wordlist=/path/to/wordlist`, where you have `--wordlist: /path/to/wordlist`.

Full correct command for you:
`john --format=raw-md5 --wordlist=/usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt crack.txt` (password files go to the end)

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked perfectly! It's a rather strange syntax for a CLI tool, don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by correcting my syntax and adding the "=" character, as in wordlist=/usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the wordlists I have downloaded from the inter-webs have had malformed utf-8 contents.  You can run this Linux command to clean up the UTF-8 by removing any non UTF-8 characters:

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 -c rockyou.txt
```

It's also wise to clean up any leading white-space since I don't know how john the ripper or other cracking applications will deal with it.

```
sed "s/^[ \t]*//" -i rockyou.txt
```